# How do I know my PCF8951 is not broken?

Tags: hardware, i2c

I am using some PCF8951 board like this:

[image]

I remove all the jumper, like this:

[image]

This is every thing:

[image]

Then I plug two senor board to this board. Everything plugs into AIN0 will get the correct value. But each of them plugs into AIN1 (or AIN2, AIN3) will not get the correct value.

My codes are written in Python. Using the code from https://github.com/ShuDiamonds/PCF8591. Code like this:

```
def analogRead0(self):
    self.i2c.writeReg8(self.dev, 0x48,0x40)
    self.i2c.readReg8(self.dev,0x48)    #read dummy
    return self.i2c.readReg8(self.dev,0x48)

def analogRead1(self):
    self.i2c.writeReg8(self.dev, 0x48,0x41)
    self.i2c.readReg8(self.dev,0x48)    #read dummy
    return self.i2c.readReg8(self.dev,0x48)

def analogRead2(self):
    self.i2c.writeReg8(self.dev, 0x48,0x42)
    self.i2c.readReg8(self.dev,0x48)    #read dummy
    return self.i2c.readReg8(self.dev,0x48)

def analogRead3(self):
    self.i2c.writeReg8(self.dev, 0x48,0x43)
    self.i2c.readReg8(self.dev,0x48)    #read dummy
    return self.i2c.readReg8(self.dev,0x48)
```

My question is how I know there is something wrong in the hardware? Or in my code?

I know my senors are good, I used my multimeter to measure the voltage between AO and GND, they are all good.

Comment: Can we have a photo showing how you are connecting to the inputs?

Comment: Your analogRead methods look OK.  I would suggest not to use any sensors, but just use 1.5V or 3.0V DC batteries.  This just narrow down the troubleshooting area. Or rename AnalogRead0 to AnalogRead7, AnalogRead 1 to AndlogRead9 etc, just to catch any careless typos.  And if you once applies high voltages to the AIN1 to AIN3 inputs, you might have fried them.

Comment: @joan Thanks. I edited the post. Add a photo. I have a raindrop detector and a temperature sensor. They both can get the correct value when they plug in AIN0 separately.

Comment: @tlfong01 Thanks. I will try your method first.

Comment: I see that you have 3 PCF8591 modules.  If you swap them for troubleshooting, you can easily catch the bad guy.  Good luck!  Ah sorry, you have only one PCF8591.  My apologies. In that case, buy one or two more to do swap, compare and contrast testing.  Those modules are so dirt cheap, so it worth your money to get spares for troubleshooting or maintenance later.

Comment: @tlfong01 These 3 photos are the same PCF8591 module. If I have more modules I may already find the problem.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake of thinking you have 3 PCF8591.  By the way, what were the wrong reading of AIN1 to 3?  All zeros or all high.  Ah, I am going out to east, so see you late evening or tomorrow.  Good luck.

Comment: @tlfong01 AIN1-AIN3 will get the same value of AIN0. And I try to use the 3.3v from the main board, only AIN0 will get 255. Other AIN still not function. Maybe as you say, I might have fried them.

Comment: Try my software at http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_PCF8591 to check the device (Python needs the pigpio daemon to be running, `sudo pigpiod`).

Comment: @Tinyfool, yes, very likely that you fried them.  By the way, your analogRead0/1/2/3 methods are a bit clumsy.  You can tidy them up and make it less error prone by using just one method, with one parameter, channel number, N.  So you can call the same method with a channel number, like analogRead(channelNum).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't why, and I buy three same components and still get the same problem. So I switch this code https://github.com/sunfounder/SunFounder_SensorKit_for_RPi2/blob/master/Python/PCF8591.py

And everything now is ok.